# Can't start up GCompris

Tags: 10.10

I installed the `ubuntu-edu-primary` pacakage successfully, and went to start GCompris from the Education menu, but got nothing.

Comment: Run it from the terminal and post the output so we can get an idea on what is going wrong.

Comment: ok, going to do it.

Comment: $gcompris -wD, got "Database is broken, it is copyed in /home/thomas/.config/gcompris/gcompris_sqlite.db.broken"

Comment: (gcompris:11461): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion `!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed
segmentation fault

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is [this bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcompris/+bug/656888) which was marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcompris/+bug/625301).

For future reference, similar bugs can be reported by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then entering `ubuntu-bug gcompris`. This will allow the developers to help improve gcompris. (The same procedure is used for any application.)

Comment: yes, use fcitx instead of ibus, gcompris is running well now.